# Wrong rule used in bison

Tags: c, syntax, compilation, bison

I am trying to perform a syntax analysis using bison, but it uses the wrong rule at one point and I didn't manage to find how to fix it.
I have a few rules but these ones seem to be the source of the problem :

```
method : vars statements;

vars : //empty
  | vars var;

var : type IDENTIFIER ';';

type : IDENTIFIER;

statements : //empty
  | statements statement;

statement : IDENTIFIER '=' e ';';

e : (...)
```

With IDENTIFIER being a simple regex matching [a-zA-Z]*

So basically, if I write that :

```
int myint;
myint = 12;
```

Since myint is an identifier, bison seems to still try to match it on the second line as a type and then matches the whole thing as a var and not as a statement. So I get this error (knowing that ASSIGN is '=') :

> syntax error, unexpected ASSIGN, expecting IDENTIFIER

Edit : Note that bison is indicating that there are shift/reduce errors, so it may be linked (as said in the answers).

Comment: Is bison reporting shift-reduce conflicts, as @chrisdodd suggests? If so, you should definitely have included that information in your question.

Comment: It did report conflicts, so I edited my question in case it might help people in the future. Thanks for the feeddback.

Comment: Shift-reduce conflicts are usually an indication that the grammar is ambiguous and that Bison has made an arbitrary *a priori* choice between the alternatives. Sometimes the choice Bison makes is correct, and in such cases you should usually eliminate the warning, for example by using an equivalent precedence declaration. (See, for example, the dangling-else ambiguity). Most of the time, the conflict was unexpected and indicates that some inputs will be parsed incorrectly. So you should take the conflict warning as a call to action, not as something you can think about later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is coming from the default resolution of the shift-reduce conflict you have due to the empty `statements` rule -- it needs to know whether to reduce the empty `statement` and start matching statements, or shift the IDENTIFIER that might begin another var.  So it decides to shift, which puts it down the var path.

You can avoid this problem by refactoring the grammar to avoid empty productions:

```
method: vars | vars statements | statements ;
vars: var | vars var ;
statements : statement | statements statement ;
... rest the same
```

which avoids needing to know whether something is var or a statement until after shifting far enough into it to tell.